# Can you share an example of using class based view with MonthMixin?

Tags: python, django

I have a news on my site done with "James Bennett - Practical Django Projects, 2nd Edition (2009)". So I am using a date-based views, which will be deprecated in django-1.4. How can I just convert my views and urls to class-based views ? May be you have seen this, please just post a link, I can't find any working example, at least for MonthMixin.

Comment: Have you seen [that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/generic-views-migration/)? May help you if you just want to convert function-based into class-based views.

Comment: Exactly, thanks, I just don't understand what mixins are, so I have a fear for class based views :) My eyes now opened :) And django.views.generic.date_based have a strange behavior - it's gives me a 15 news entries by default. I believe i can have a problem how to solve this in class based views.

Answer (score 2):

Django has a [detailed list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView) of all the new class-based views and their mixins.

You don't need to use `MonthMixin` directly unless you're doing something special. For just a generic month-based archive view, use `MonthArchiveView`. Sub-class it and go.

If you need any further help you'll have to give us more specifics on exactly what you need.

Comment: I am thinked that mixins is mandatory, so my brains is stuck, so when you said that I don't need to use MonthMixin directly, I found a link - http://martinogden.me/2011/03/27/quick-look-django-13-class-based-views/ So I must do it like that ?

Comment: Not at all. `MonthArchiveView` already includes `MonthMixin`. It's ready to go. Again, if you're having a specific problem, give the details on that (Edit your question, don't post extended bits of code in comments).

Comment: just a follow up to both my answer below and Chris' answer. You can look at the Django docs and follow the generic CBV all the way up the chain. That way you know what views offer what out of the box, what you can over-ride, and if you do indeed need a completely custom mixin setup.

Answer (score 0):

Think of CBV, more specifically "Generic Class Based Views" as a large tree of Python classes. Starting with the simplest class. Each one subclasses and over rides methods from one another. For example, the ArchiveIndexView is typically the view you will sub-class for the index of your site. It adds an extra context variable called latest. You must supply it with a date_field, num_latest, and a couple optionals in the view class. You can also pass these arguements in through the URLConf. However, it is more tidy and clean to have the logic in the views.py . It is quite convenient once you get the hang of it. You can create mixins of your own that essentially are as powerful as your brain. Beyond, a mixin though for something you want available on every page then perhaps a template tag or a custom context processor at worst.